# discord自動送信botのbotのアイコン画像の変え方がわからない。

Tags: google-apps-script, discord

**やりたいこと、わからないこと**
GASを使用してGoogleスプレットシートの内容をdiscordに送信したいと考えているのですが、
botのicon画像を変えるやり方がわかりません。

具体的にどのようなコードを組めばできるかわかる方教えて下さい。

下のコードは実際に問題なく動き、discordに文章を送れるのですが、iconだけデフォルトの状態です。

**実際のコード**

```
  discord()
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet1 = get_sheet('スプレットシートURL1',0);
  
    var datecoord = sheet1.getRange(2,3);
    var date = datecoord.getValue();
      //format
    var formatcoord = sheet1.getRange(3, 3);
    var format = formatcoord.getValue();

    
   
    var messages_array = []; // initialize
    //var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow()-10;
    //console.log(lastRow);
  for (let i = 11; i <= 16; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet1.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
    var message = 'None'
    if (haisintime > 0) {
      var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
      } 
    
    messages_array.push(message); // push
  }
  return messages_array; // return
    
  
};

//googleスプレットシート  自動送信
function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};


function get_sheet2(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var discord = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet2 = discord.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet2;
};

function discord(message) {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet2('スプレットシートURL2',0);

    var messages = get_value();  // call get_value() at here

    var lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();  //最終行取得
    
    for (let j = 11; j <= lastRow2; j++) {

      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,3);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();

    //token
      var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(j,4);
      var dtoken = tokencoord.getValue();
      
  　//channel
      var channelcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,2);
      var dchannel = channelcoord.getValue();
      
    //format
      const url        = webhook;
      const token      = dtoken;
      const channel    = dchannel;
      const text       = messages[j-11];
      if (text === 'None') {
        console.log(channel + " : 送信なし"); 
        continue;
      }

      
      

      const username   = 'bot名';
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
      };

      const params = {
          'method' : method,
          'payload' : payload,
          'muteHttpExceptions': true   

      };
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    //実行ログ
    console.log(channel + " : " + text); 


    }
    
}
```

**試したこと**
discord()関数に　const icon = "https://github.com/qiita.png"　を追加したが変化はなかった。

```
const username   = 'bot名';
      const icon = "https://github.com/qiita.png";
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'icon'       : icon,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記のように`avatar_url`として追加するのはいかがでしょうか。

```
const payload = {
    'token'      : token,
    'channel'    : channel,
    "content"    : text,
    'username'   : username,
    'parse'      : parse,
    'avatar_url': "https://github.com/qiita.png" // Added
};
```

#### Reference:

- [Webhook Resource](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook)

Comment: ありがとうございます。ローカルの画像を使用する方法はあるでしょうか？@Tanaike

Comment: @zumo1224 ご返事ありがとうございます。無事解決したとのことで安心しました。`ローカルの画像を使用する方法はあるでしょうか？`という新しい質問について、その場合は、例えば[Modify Webhook](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#modify-webhook)を使ってavatarを変更するのはいかがでしょうか。ただ、GASで動作させているようですので、ローカルの画像を使用する場合は、一度Google Driveあるいはその他のStorageへアップロードする必要があると思います。例えば、今ご使用のスクリプトは、Web AppsやDialogなどのHTML上で動作しているのでしょうか。実際の状況が分からず申し訳ありません。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。ローカルではありませんが、GoogleDriveに入れた画像を取得することができました。　方法としては、次のURL:https://qiita.com/codeDiver/items/0394968fa318d930　を参考にGoogledriveのimg画像を直接呼び出せるようなURLの形にし、そのURLをコードに張り付けた結果アクセスすることができました！